# Tried to convert MSISDN ( Phone No ) as an input to E.164 formatted dotted string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-mvc, java-8

I have an input MSISDN ( phone no.) 7876301675

But now I am trying to convert this phone no. into E.164 format ( dotted string )

Input : tel: +1 7876301675 Required Output : 5.7.6.1.0.3.6.7.8.7.e164.arpa

Here telephone no. +1 7876301675 translated into domain name 5.7.6.1.0.3.6.7.8.7.e164.arpa in reverse order

```
public void EditReqest( Request <Document > requests) {
    String phone = "0";
    ResourceKey msisdns = requests.getKey("msisdn");
    String msisdn = " ";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\\\.(.$)");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(msisdn);
     if(m.find())
      msisdn = matcher.group(1);
      Document docs =XMLUtil.getDocument();
      Element roots = docs.createElement("Creating");
      doc.appendChild(roots);
      roots.setAttributre("msisdn", msisdn);
      Document d = (Document) requests.getPayload();
      if(d != null) {
       Element e = d.getDocumentElement();
       if ( e != null) {
         if(requests.getSecondaryKey("phone") e != nul )
             phone = 
             requests.getSecondaryy("phone").getValue();
              if (! "1".equals(phone)) 
                  phone = "0";
             String  id = getValueFromElement(e, "id");
             String text = getValueFromElement(e, "text");
             String offer = getValueFromElement(e, "offer");
             if ( ! " ".equals (offer)) { 
               offer = offer.trim();
               StringBuffer sOffer = new String buffer();
               sOffer.append("(");
               String[] pOffer = offer.split("\\|\\|");
                  for (String pOffer : pOffer )
                      sOffer.append("textOffer=\” ");
                       sOffer.append(sOffer);
                       sOffer.append("\" ");
                       sOffer.append("| |");
                  }
                sOffer.delete(sOffer.length() -2,  sOffer.length());
                 sOffer.append(")");
                  addOrSetElement ( e, "offer", sOffer.toString());
           }
            text = convertText ( phone, id, text) ;
            addOrSetElement ( e, "text", text );
            Node n = l.importNode( e, true);
            roots.appendChild(n);
      }
  }
 requests.setPayload(l);
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you please improve the code indentation (by using your IDE's builtin function), so your code becomes easier to read?

Comment: And I guess there are a few typos in the code. Does it compile without error?